# Sharing PC's internet connection with laptop using Symbian smartphone

Tags: wireless-networking, connection-sharing, symbian

I have PC without any wifi adapter installed and I have Nokia C6-00 smartphone with Symbian S60 5th edition. On my PC I have a ADSL internet connection and I want to share it via my phone wifi to other wifi devices like notebook, iPad, iPod. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: jeez :-) what a crasy hop to try and attempt, should be possible the noki phone will take internet in via the USB using "active Sync" connection (windows and kinda slow) That leaves having a piece of software (on phone) that will send it back out as "access point" via the wi-fi. . . . If you got $30 and a USB port on the PC, you can use a cheap Wi-Fi adapter and "Virtual Router", save a step through symbian world and be done with it.